# Inkscape too slow when importing R plots

Tags: performance, r, inkscape

I am trying to import R plots for editing in inkscape (tried bot svg and pdf). Once I do so inkscape becomes too slow. Is there any solution to this problem? I tried to simplify the paths through PATH/simplify but there was no significant improvement
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, probably not. My guess is that you are trying to edit R plots with many data points, which then translates to many SVG elements in Inkscape.

Inkscape handles well relatively small to moderately complex/involved graphics, but consumes large amounts of RAM once many SVG elements are rendered to the canvas, even if each element is small.

You can try a couple of things: (a) try opening Inkscape on a more powerful computer with lots of RAM; (b) see if you can create an R plot which conveys the same meaning, but has fewer data points/elements; (c) try to dig around the web to find an unofficial 64-bit version of Inkscape. Alternatively, if editing the plots is a one-off, consider trialing Adobe Illustrator 64-bit and creating SVG plots this way.

Sorry I could not be of more help.